# How can I get my table header elements to refresh after updating sort icon CSS classes in Blazor WASM app?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Dotnet Blazor WASM app, I am building a table with sortable columns. I'm trying to display a sort arrow in the column header to reflect the currently sorted column and direction. I'm using a function to return the css class I want shown for the icon in each column header. The table headers display correctly on first render, but aren't updating when the values change.

```html
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="clickable" onclick='@(async () => await SortAsync("Name"))'>
                File name
                <i class='@SortIcon("Name")'></i>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="clickable" onclick='@(async () => await SortAsync("Intent"))'>
                Intent
                <i class='@SortIcon("Intent")'></i>
            </th>
 ...
```

```cs
    private string SortIcon(string columnName)
    {
      if (SortField != columnName)
      {
        Logger.LogInformation("SortIcon: {columnName} fas fa-sort", columnName);
        return "fas fa-sort";
      }

      Logger.LogInformation("SortIcon: {columnName} {sortDirection}", columnName, SortDirection == 0 ? "fas fa-sort-up" : "fas fa-sort-down");
      return SortDirection == 0 ? "fas fa-sort-up" : "fas fa-sort-down";
    }
```

Do I need to manually trigger something to get the table header elements to re-evaluate + refresh the DOM?  I have some logging information in the `SortIcon` method, and can see the correct values evaluated as I click different columns to sort.  But the UI is not showing updated icons as the values change.

Have also tried storing the CSS values in a dictionary, and programmatically updating the dictionary entries to store the correct CSS class for each column, but didn't see any different behavior with that approach.